# Kill Opened CSV File

Tags: excel, vba

So i have code to copy data from one csv to another open Excel xlsx file but what i am trying to do is to kill the csv file once process is done. the code works but the kill part is not working, what am i doing wrong here?

```
Sub MasterData()
Dim getfilestg As String

    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set reporting = ActiveWorkbook

Set rep = Sheets("Master Data")


 For Each reportSF In Application.Workbooks
        reportSF.Activate

        If Range("A1").Value Like "GoldTier ID" And Range("AT1").Value Like "Owner's TL" Then reportSF.Activate: Exit For
        Next reportSF
If Not reportSF Is Nothing Then

reporting.Activate
rep.Activate
endLine = Range("A1").Offset(Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row

 reportSF.Activate
endLine = Range("A1").Offset(Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
reportSF.Sheets(1).Range("A1:AT" & endLine).Copy
reporting.Activate
rep.Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End If

If reportSF.ActiveCell.Value = "Account" Then
getfilestg = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.csv), *.csv")

Kill (getfilestg)
End If

Range("A1").Select


End Sub
```

Comment: Is the file you are selecting still open?

Comment: When going through the files you might want to close them (reportSF.close) cannot kill a read only file.

Comment: Yes the file is open, so i could possibly do a .close then do the kill?

Comment: Yes, my assumption is that you are trying to kill reportSF?,

Comment: if you are using kill you must supply kill with full path and extension.For example:
Kill "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\FILENAME.EXTENSION"

Comment: Yes, i want to delete it once the copy is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the following code:

```
If reportSF.ActiveCell.Value = "Account" Then
getfilestg = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.csv), *.csv")

Kill (getfilestg)
End If
```

with:

```
If reportSF.Sheet(1).Range("A1").Value = "Account" Then '<-- change range here
getfilestg = reportSF.FullName
reportSF.Close
Kill (getfilestg)
End If
```

This will close and delete reportSF

Comment: For some reason, it does not like this part:If reportSF.ActiveCell.Value = "Account" Then. I get "Runtime 438" object doesnt support this property or method.

Comment: I removed the IF and just used the getfilestg till the Kill but it does not know where the path of reportSF is.

Comment: replace ActiveCell.value with Sheets(1).Range("A1").value

Comment: My bad, you need to use FullName instead of Path to return full directory, i have updated the code in my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed it perfectly.